# Retrieve Structured Xml from Sql Server Express 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, sql-server-2005

I would like to have xml output from Full Text Search indexed tables like below. but my code generates incorrect syntax near union
**my code**

```
SELECT
Table1.Name 'Table1/Name',
Table1.Email 'Table1/Email',
(    SELECT
     Table2.Address 'Address',
     Table2.Phone 'Phone',
     FROM Details Table2
     INNER JOIN Regd Table3 ON Table3.Code = Table2.Code
     AND (Table3.SubCode = xml.SubCode) AND (Table1.Id = Table3.Id)
     FOR XML PATH ('Details'),Type) as 'Table1',
FROM Users Table1
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Users,[Name], @SearchKeys) AS KEY_TBL ON Id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
INNER JOIN Regd Table3 ON Table3.Id = Table1.Id,
OPENXML (@idoc,'/Request/List',2)
WITH (SubCode NVARCHAR(20)) as xml
WHERE  (xml.SubCode = '' or Table3.SubCode = xml.SubCode) AND (Table3.Id = Table1.Id)
FOR XML PATH ('List')
UNION
SELECT
SELECT
Table1.Name 'Table1/Name',
Table1.Email 'Table1/Email',
(    SELECT
     Table2.Address 'Address',
     Table2.Phone 'Phone',
     FROM Details Table2
     INNER JOIN Regd Table3 ON Table3.Code = Table2.Code
     AND (Table3.SubCode = xml.SubCode) AND (Table1.Id = Table3.Id)
     FOR XML PATH ('Details'),Type) as 'Table1',
FROM Users Table1
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Users,[Email], @SearchKeys) AS KEY_TBL ON Id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
INNER JOIN Regd Table3 ON Table3.Id = Table1.Id,
OPENXML (@idoc,'/Request/List',2)
WITH (SubCode NVARCHAR(20)) as xml
WHERE  (xml.SubCode = '' or Table3.SubCode = xml.SubCode) AND (Table3.Id = Table1.Id)
FOR XML PATH ('List')
```

here is out put i expected to have

```
<List>
<Table1>
<Name></Name>
<Email></Email>
<Details>
<Address></Address>
<Phone></Phone>
</Details>
</Table1>
</List>
```

i think request xml parameter would not be of any use here as it is just a syntax error

Comment: Can you **explain** a bit what you're trying to do?? You're just throwing a huge complicated SQL statement at us, with no background, no information about the tables involved, their structure, their data etc. What e.g. is that `@idoc` you're using in two places... how does that get populated, from what data?? Could you maybe **simplify** this to a single `SELECT` and leave out the `UNION` part for now!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of syntax errors in your code but I assume they are there because you have removed a lot of stuff that you thought was not necessary.

The error you say you get is `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'`.

This will give you that error,

```
select *
from YourTable
for xml path('list')
union
select *
from YourTable
for xml path('list')
```

You have to embed the queries in a select statement like this.

```
select
(select *
 from YourTable
 for xml path('list'))
union
select
(select *
 from YourTable
 for xml path('list'))
```

If you want the columns to be of XML type you need to add `type` and use `union all` because `The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.`

```
select
(select *
 from YourTable
 for xml path('list'), type)
union all
select
(select *
 from YourTable
 for xml path('list'), type)
```

I have no idea if this eventually will give you the output you want but this is the reason for `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'` and what you can do about it.

Comment: +1 for explaining the why's of doing something solves the problem

Comment: Alert , how do i make it account for null values of columns it doesn't generate me a empty `<Details></Details>` xml element when the `address` , `Phone` elements are null/empty

Comment: @Deeptechtons – I think you have to ask a new question about this, including some sample code and expected output. When I test with `null` values I do get a empty Details tag that look like this `<Details />`

Comment: i completely agree here is the link to new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729270/for-xml-type-generating-null-element-tags-in-sql-server-2005-express-2005)