# For xml type generating null element tags in sql server 2005 express 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml, sql-server-2005

Hi i tried the below but it doesn't generate xml element for empty/null values. Could someone point me the mistake i am making.
**Xml Output i expect**

```
  <Board>
    <BoardId>1</BoardId>
    <Title>Introduction to modal popup control</Title>
    <Desc>The ModalPopup extender allows you to display content in an element that</Desc>
  </Board>
  <Comment>
    <CommentId>1</CommentId>
    <Comment>Typing a comment and sending it is such a neat stuff</Comment>
    <Date>2011-03-25T15:24:43</Date>
  </Comment>
  <Comment>
    <CommentId>2</CommentId>
    <Comment>Board comment 123 123 123</Comment>
    <Date></Date>
  </Comment>
</Board>
```

Notice the empty date element in the last comment tag element.
Actual output got,

```
  <Board>
    <BoardId>1</BoardId>
    <Title>Introduction to modal popup control</Title>
    <Desc>The ModalPopup extender allows you to display content in an element that</Desc>
  </Board>
  <Comment>
    <CommentId>1</CommentId>
    <Comment>Typing a comment and sending it is such</Comment>
    <Date>2011-03-25T15:24:43</Date>
  </Comment>
  <Comment>
    <CommentId>2</CommentId>
    <Comment>Board comment 123 123 123</Comment>
  </Comment>
</Board>
```

notice that date tag is not present at all.
 Here is the sql code

```
SELECT
Board.BoardId  'Board/BoardId',
Board.BoardTitle 'Board/Title',
ISNULL(Board.BoardDesc,'')  'Board/Desc',
(
SELECT 
Comments.CommentId 'CommentId',
Comments.Comment 'Comment',
isnull(Comments.CreatedOn,'') 'Date'
from us_boardcomments comments where comments.boardId = board.boardid
for xml path('Comment'),type
)
FROM US_Board Board where boardId = '1'
for xml path('Board')
```

**2. Also if i add OrderBy or GroupBy or Distict i get error.**

**More Info:**
The xml acts as DataSource to DataSet which is read using ReadXml method of the DataSet class.

Comment: Does `FOR XML PATH('foo'), ELEMENTS XSINIL` do what you need?

Comment: @Martin nope, i don't want any extra attributes and fancy stuff to indicate that a value is null. Do you know any other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually don't see exactly what you see. I get the value `1900-01-01T00:00:00` when `CreatedOn is null`.

I guess this behaviour is because CreatedOn is datetime. If the XML is validated against a XSD, empty tags for xs:dateTime is not allowed.

To get what you want you can do like this.

```
isnull(convert(varchar(19), Comments.CreatedOn, 126), '') 'Date',
```

Result (for me) is `<Date />` when `CreatedOn is null`

**Edit 1** Empty Comment tag with empty tags, when there are no comments

```
SELECT
Board.BoardId  'Board/BoardId',
Board.BoardTitle 'Board/Title',
ISNULL(Board.BoardDesc,'')  'Board/Desc',
(
SELECT 
isnull(convert(varchar(10), Comments.CommentId), '') 'CommentId',
isnull(Comments.Comment, '') 'Comment',
isnull(convert(varchar(19), Comments.CreatedOn, 126),'') 'Date'
from US_Board Board2
  left outer join us_boardcomments comments
    on comments.boardId = Board2.boardid
  where Board2.boardid = Board.boardid
for xml path('Comment'),type
)
FROM US_Board Board where boardId = '1'
for xml path('Board')
```

Result

```
<Board>
  <Board>
    <BoardId>1</BoardId>
    <Title>Introduction to modal popup control</Title>
    <Desc>The ModalPopup extender allows you to display content in an element that</Desc>
  </Board>
  <Comment>
    <CommentId />
    <Comment />
    <Date />
  </Comment>
</Board>
```

Comment: @Mickael try it for a entry where entry does not exists lol funny but i would like it to generate a `<Comment></Comment>` tag when a board does not have any comments at all. actually will it be possible to generate whole stuff like `<Comment><CommentId/><Comment/><Date/></Comment>` when no entries exists.

Comment: @Mickael you ROCK you seem to be a Sql Guru i am a sql inter guy could you advice me with mastering the language

Comment: @Deeptechtons – I would recommend spending time on StackOverflow trying to answer questions and learn from answers given by others. That is what I do :).